# Unsupported format character python coding

Tags: python, gps

```
def GPSPositionChanged(e):  
    source = e.device     
    print("F%, F%, F%") %(e.latitude, e.longitude, e.altitude)
```

Brings an error of

```
unsupported character ',' (0x2c) at index 2.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post full traceback error msg along with an example of `e` object?

Comment: Try  replacing all the `%` with `%f`... (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: @thebjorn I swapped F% with %f, worked perfect thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `%` in the wrong place, it should be:

```
print("%F, %F, %F") % (e.latitude, e.longitude, e.altitude)
```